# Parking Lot Search Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search

I got a street with an infinite length which is parked with cars. However I cannot see a free parking lot anywhere but I know that there must be exactly one free spot somewhere where I can park my car. The aim is to take the shortest way and I can only go left or right.

Assuming I knew in which direction the free parking lot is, I would directly drive to that direction and thereby I would pass "A" taken parking lots.

[image: Pic of problem]

Now I need an algorithm that needs to pass no more than 10*A parking lots to find a free parking lot. And I start in front of my home... "A" is not known.

I would begin by seeing the street as an array and the parked cars are the elements of the array. True signifies an empty spot and false means it is occupied. The search is done till that boolean value is found to be true. That would be my basic idea. But what's more important than that is how is the search done.

I would maybe go one way, then twice as far the other way, loop, so I got something like: 1, -2, 4, -8, 16,... till I found the empty spot.

But I'm not sure if it would be solved in less than 10*A...

Comment: This makes no sense. If the free parking spots are at random, and there is no incentive to find a parking spot closer to your house there is just to choose a direction and drive till you find a spot.

Comment: @jornare He phrased it oddly, but there's only guaranteed to be one spot; so if you pick the wrong direction, you could go forever without finding a spot.

Comment: So... this sounds like homework, and I don't want to solve it for you outright, but I'm happy to give you a hint: Using the algorithm you describe, backtrack from when you've found the target car. In terms of `A`, how many cars have you passed once? Twice? `k` times? If you add together all the cars you've passed at least once, plus at least twice, etc, you'll get the total distance traveled...

Comment: You guys in the same class? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37393245/java-algorithm-to-find-free-car-park-as-fast-as-possible

Comment: be honest... you replaced the original L in your picture with an A, didn´t you? :)

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice, and please do not create new accounts to try to get around the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's apply a kind of algorithm as you indicated and continue for as long as the empty parking lot has not been found:

1. Go left  until parking lot 1 at the left of the starting point and go back to starting point;
2. Go right until parking lot 2 at the right of the starting point and go back to starting point;
3. Go left  until parking lot 4 at the left of the starting point and go back to starting point;
4. Go right until parking lot 8 at the right of the starting point and go back to starting point;

So at step **n**, you will first go **2<sup>n-1</sup>** lots away from the starting point, and  travel the same distance back, so in that step you travel a total of **2<sup>n</sup>** lots.

Taking the distance travelled during the previous steps, that makes that after step **n** that total distance is **Σ<sub>i=1..n</sub> (2<sup>i</sup>)**, which is **2<sup>n+1</sup> - 2**.

So if the free parking lot is **A** lots away from the starting point, then that lot will be visited in step **ceil(logA)+1** if we are lucky about the side, or else one step later, i.e. in step **ceil(logA)+2**.

So taking the worst case (the second), the total travelled distance is the one for step **ceil(logA)+1**, plus the remaining steps to get to lot **A** from the starting point during the last step (which gets interrupted). That comes to **2<sup>(ceil(logA)+1)+1</sup> - 2**, (which is a value between **4A-2** and **8A-3**) plus **A**. That is less than **9A-2**, and thus meets the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works.

The maximum farthest distance you could have driven to the wrong side is 2*A. Total distance driven on the wrong side is 2A+A+A/2...=4A

The total maximum distance travelled on the right side is A + A + A/2+A/4... = 3A

So at most you would need to travel 7*A.

Eg. A=9. Wrong side = 16+8+4+2+1=31.
Right side=9+8+4+2+1 = 24

Total = 55 < 7*9 = 63.

PS: Okay. I slightly misread your problem. But the methodology remains same. I will leave the rest for you to work out.

Comment: I'm not sure this is valid -- note that the points reached e.g. on the positive side are 1, 4, 16, etc. (not 1, 2, 4, 8)