# Minimum Steps from Source to Destination

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We have a path on the x axis from 1 to N. There are 2 points namely source, S and destination, D on the path. Starting from the source S, We are allowed to make only 2 moves. We can either jump U steps forward or jump L steps backward. If we are at some position p, we can either move to p+U or p-L in a single step, provided they remain in the [1,N] range. What is the minimum number of steps required to reach the destination D from S? We are not allowed to reach beyond the boundaries 1 and N.

Comment: And...your question is?

Comment: You really need to define the problem better. As written, it makes little sense. Just figure out the direction from S to D and take as many steps in the proper direction as necessary. Somehow, I think there's more to the question, but your description doesn't say.

Comment: Maybe you want an optimal algorithm that starts in S, but does not know what D is. Instead it must try. Only if it reaches D, the algorithm will know it did. D could be less or greater than S. If this is your question, you should have explained it like that, but then this has been asked before. See [Parking Lot Search Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422823/parking-lot-search-alg).

Answer (score 0):

So we have to make D - S steps and want the minimal `x+y`:

```
D - S = x * U - y * L

y = (Ux + S-D) / L
```

This is math. So we can exploit symmetry in the problem and assume D > S (if so desired), U > 0, L > 0.

To exactly hit D, `Ux+S-D % L` must be 0 (% is the modulo operator).

Either clever math or loop over x.

I hope this gets you started.

---

As I am aware that depending on the math treated the cleverness may vary. If they treated gcd and modulo:

```
Let g = gcd(U, L)
```

then there is no solution when `(D-S) % g != 0`.
For instance you cannot reach for 3 to 6 with L 2, and U 4.